# Why using containerGroup is preventing my other listeners to work?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

My application is listening to several topics.
Some of them are compacted topics used to load in memory some data.

I wanted to load first thoses data, so I used a SmartLifecycle to manually start those container before the other containers.

It's working great, but for simplicity, I tried to use a containerGroup

```
@KafkaListener(id = "myId", containerGroup = "compacted", ...)
```

Then in the SmartLifecycle bean I used :

```
        Collection<MessageListenerContainer> compactedListenerContainers = applicationContext.getBean("compacted", Collection.class);
```

But once I do that, after the "start" method is finished, the other containers are never started.

If I replace this line by :

```
Collection<MessageListenerContainer> compactedListenerContainers = Arrays.asList(registry.getListenerContainer("myId"));
```

Its working.

Any idea why getting the bean for a containerGroup prevent all other listener to work ? Knowing that all other @KafkaListeners are just defined by :

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic")
```

**Edit**

After further investigations, the problem is related to the KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.

If the SmartLifeCycle bean is created with "KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry" as a dependency the application is working. Even if I'm not using the registry at all.

But if the SmartLifeCycle bean is created without this registry, the application fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show your container factory.

I presume you have `autoStartup` set to false since you are manually starting them.

So the others won't start either; since you want to start them after your compacted topics are loaded, simply call `start()` on the endpoint registry and it will start the others.

Or you can put the others in another `containerGroup`.

Comment: I'll update tomorrow with the factories.But there are 2 different factories, one autoStartup and the other not. But for me the key here is that by swapping those 2 lines the behavior changes. Why ? I'm just getting the container differently, not interracting with them nor especially interracting with the blocked ones.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why there would be a difference; but I am confused; I thought you didn't want the other containers to start until your compacted logs had been loaded. Perhaps a small sample app would help me see what you are doing.

Comment: did you have time to found out something ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have a chance to look at this last week. It's because the registry returns `true` from `isRunning()` if **any** of its registered containers is running. I didn't write that code, so I am not sure what the intended logic was there. In the next release, I'll change the registry to have its own lifecycle status; in the meantime, you can call `registry.getListenerContainers().foreach(c -> c.start())`.

Comment: Oh ok, but why having the registry as parameter in my bean creation matters ? Since in my example adding/removing it changes the behavior. Your advice is to add ```registry.getListenerContainers().foreach(c -> c.start())``` at the end of my ```start()``` method in my ```SmartLifeCycle``` bean ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by `but why having the registry as parameter in my bean creation matters ? `. Yes, you can do it there.

Comment: In my github repo the difference between the line 59 and 64 of ```KafkaConfiguration ``` is the ```KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry ``` presence in the parameters. Knowing that the line 59 version is working

Comment: By adding that parameter, you have effectively made the registry a dependency of the `CompactedTopicsInitializer`. See the javadocs for `DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart()` - `Start the specified bean as part of the given set of Lifecycle beans, making sure that any beans that it depends on are started first.` So, even though the registry is in a later phase, it is actually started before your initializer (it will only start `autoStartup` containers though). Since it's called first, `isRunning()` returns false.

Comment: Ok perfect, thanks for the explication. Making it depends on the registry was in fact breaking what I intented to do. The registry was started before my bean. So I have to inject the registry in my bean without having it depends on registry ? xD